# Creating a Daemon based sftp client

Tags: linux, daemon

If i were to build an sftp client which launched with logon details, and could then controlled by sending commands to that daemon; would that be ideal way to create an sftp client with disposable credentials?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "disposable credentials"?

Comment: i mean the daemon can only be connected to one server and it waits for commands, but when you are finished you have to tell it to connect again and wait for further commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe such clients already exist:

- `sshfs`

  ```
  sshfs host:path ~/mnt
  ```
- SFTP modules for GNOME's GVFS and KDE's Kio

  ```
  gvfs-mount sftp://host/path
  ```

All of these run as daemons and are controllable through standard operating system functions (read directory, open file, etc.).